# Exporting jar in eclipse with VM args

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I've scavenged around the internet for a few hours, but can't seem to get this working just yet. I'm making a small game using lwjgl and slick2d in eclipse. I had to set the VM arguments as such, "java -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Subsage\Development\slick"

When I export the project, eclipse tells me that the VM args aren't exported with it, and so when I try to run the jar...nothing happens. Is there a trivial fix for this? I looked at using several wrappers and tried several, but I can't get it running. I feel I'm doing it incorrectly, but there aren't many explanations out there for me to read up on.

I don't have much experience using .bat files or any wrappers by the way, if that would perhaps explain my ineptitude.

Comment: 0 down vote
 

If you would use some buildtool (for example Maven) you can configurethe contents of the MANIFEST.MF in the exported .jar.

Are you sing any kind of buildtool?

Comment: You would need the args while executing the jar. I am not sure you can include it as part of the jar itself.  So while executing the jar, you should do    java -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Subsage\Development\slick jar yourjarfile.jar